# XPath select on child nodes

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, xpath

I am currently trying to make a new xpath on a child node. But it doesn't work.

How can I archive this?

The idea is:

```
    xpath.select('//*[contains(@class, "product-grid__item")]', doc).forEach(node => {
     node = node as Node;

     xpath.select('/a /*[contains(@class, "desc-height")] /strong', node).forEach(z => {
       z = z as Node;
       console.log(z.textContent);
     })
   })
```

But the second request does not select on the nodes, it selects on the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression

```
/a/*[contains(@class, "desc-height")]/strong
```

is an [absolute location path](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#NT-AbsoluteLocationPath) and it will evaluate equally from every context node.

You need a [relative location path](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#NT-RelativeLocationPath) like

```
a/*[contains(@class, "desc-height")]/strong
```

**Note:** some literature will always show you relative XPath expression starting with `.` [abbreviate syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#path-abbrev) like `./a/*[contains(@class, "desc-height")]/strong`. That it's not needed. Some XPath engines not aligned with the specs might only parse this kind of expression just because.